# I have private key in text file. How to generate .pem file or .cer file

Tags: certificate, rsa, x509certificate, pem

I have private key in plan text format. I want to convert to .pem or .cer file.
I have no idea about open SSL. I able to use plain text file of private key in .net application. Someone help me. How can convert it into .pem or .cer to use in our project.

Comment: Unfortunately there are many formats for private keys. "Plain text" does not narrow it down enough to allow for an answer.

Comment: Ok, I have private key like notepad like as below       -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAonTnSEw5NyH4QWYKzhceN8xy/M2Y10Qq/juoLmdzY523w/Q1
YYY97439oeruoeuroterkherhtkerjo8u30948erjoieurotiuerotueordjouer34802380238kk
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----                                 this is not good to have key in project and use this. So, no can easily temper this. that is why i want keep this key in .pem or cer file and use in .net application. Am i right way to thinking? or just use plan text format to store key and use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the content of your private key starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, the file format is **PEM** ([RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468)).

The extension `.pem` indicates that the file format is PEM. However, the extension does not tell anything about the content of the file. The content may be a private key, a public key, a certificate or something else.

The extension `.cer` indicates that the content of the file is a certificate. However, the extension does not tell anything about the file format. The format may be PEM, **DER** ([X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/)) or something else. If the content is text data and it includes `-----BEGIN ?????-----`, the format is PEM. On the other hand, if the content is binary data, it is highly likely that the format is DER.

The extension `.key` is often used to indicate that the content of the file is a private key. However, the extension does not tell anything about the file format. The format may be PEM, DER or something else.

Diagrams below from *"[Illustrated X.509 Certificate](https://medium.com/@darutk/illustrated-x-509-certificate-84aece2c5c2e)"* illustrate relationship among **ASN.1** ([X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680/))), **DER** ([X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/)), **BASE64** ([RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)) and **PEM** ([RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468)).

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM]

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM (Application to X.509 Certificate)]

If you want to convert your private key in plain text (PEM) into some kind of binary data, convert the format to DER by typing the following command.

```
openssl pkey -inform PEM -in private_key.pem -outform DER -out private_key.der
```

- `pkey` : is a subcommand for key operations.
- `-inform PEM` : indicates that the format of the input file is PEM.
- `-in private_key.pem` : specifies the input file.
- `-outform DER` : specifies DER as the output format.
- `-out private_key.der` : specifies the output file.

Comment: Great and thank you. I have converted to .PEM from private key. How to use this .PEM for security. Do we need to install like we do in case of .cer (certificate) and find by name or thumb print?

Comment: Ha ha ha (^_^; Your question is nearly equal to "How to use public-key cryptography for security?" It's a way too big topic. Public/Private keys are used in various places.

Comment: how do i generate a .key file?